# How to issue multiple commands from nestjs saga?

Tags: nestjs

I've created a saga to react on a given event. In that case, multiple commands need to be issued.

My Saga looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeSagas {
    public constructor() {}

    onSomeEvent(events$: EventObservable<any>): Observable<ICommand> {
        return events$.ofType(SomeEvent).pipe(
            map((event: SomeEvent) => {
                return of(new SomeCommand(uuid()), new SomeCommand(uuid()));
            }),
        );
    }
}
```

When debugging I found that there is an error thrown 'CommandHandler not found exception!', which is kind of confusing because in case I return only one instance of `SomeCommand` the command handler is called correctly.

Do I miss something or is the saga implementation just not supporting issuing multiple commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like I found the answer to it - it's related to RxJS:

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeSagas {
    public constructor() {}

    onSomeEvent(events$: EventObservable<any>): Observable<ICommand> {
        return events$.ofType(SomeEvent).pipe(
            map((event: SomeEvent) => {
                const commands: ICommand[] = [
                  new SomeCommand(uuid()),
                  new SomeCommand(uuid()),
                  new SomeCommand(uuid()),
                ];
                return commands;
            }),
            flatMap(c => c), // piping to flatMap RxJS operator is solving the issue I had
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `mergeMap()` to emit another observable. It will continue to emit that observable until it completes, but in your case that will happen all at once if you use an `of()` observable.

```
    onSomeEvent(events$: EventObservable<any>): Observable<ICommand> {
        return events$.ofType(SomeEvent).pipe(
            mergeMap((event: SomeEvent) => of(
                  new SomeCommand(uuid()),
                  new SomeCommand(uuid()),
                  new SomeCommand(uuid()),
            ))
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since flatMap is deprecated you can use mergeMap instead:

```
    @Injectable()
    export class Saga {
        public constructor() {}
    
        onSomeEvent(events$: EventObservable<any>): Observable<ICommand> {
            return events$.ofType(SomeEvent).pipe(
                map((event: SomeEvent) => {
                    const commands: ICommand[] = [
                      new FirstCommans(uuid()),
                      new SecondCommand(uuid()),
    
                    ];
                    return commands;
                }),
                mergeMap(c => c),
            );
        }
    }
```